# OData - Limit the number of related entities

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to make this kind of request with OData ?

"Get All *Customers* with theirs **last 5** *Orders*"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with OData v3. OData v4 has support for this. The syntax would look like,

```
~Customers?$expand=Orders($orderby=OrderID&$$top=5)
```

Refer to the V4 draft [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/csprd01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-csprd01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc355091906).

You could always do it with multiple requests though with OData V3. Using the $batch feature would let you do it in 2 requests, get all customers first and then build a [$batch](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/batch-processing/) request with GET `~/Customers(id)/Orders?$orderby=CustomerID&$top=5` for each customer in the first request.